# I am trying to select mutual friends from the database, how can I go about doing this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the session user's all mutual friends with another user.
This is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `friends_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friends_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friends_friend` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friends_date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `friends_enabled` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My friends_user can contain if the browsing user's session ID or another persons id (depending on who sent it)
and the same for friends_friend, that can contain the browsing user's session id, or the person who sent it.
So how can I get their mutual friends? Any help would be hugely apreciated.

So it could be like so:

```
friends_user | friends_friend
1                2
2                3
1                3
5                3
2                5
```

This is the sql for my friend selector, but I need to add more code to get mutual friends with another id:

```
SELECT * FROM friends 

    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.user_id = friends.friends_user AND friends.friends_user != ?
        OR users.user_id = friends.friends_friend AND friends.friends_friend != ?
    LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
        ON users.user_id = user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user

    WHERE (friends_user = ?
        AND friends_enabled = 'enabled'
        AND users.user_enabled = 'enabled')

    OR (friends_friend = ?
        AND friends_enabled = 'enabled'
        AND users.user_enabled = 'enabled')
```

Comment: What does the Internet say about mutual friends?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry

Comment: here is pseudocode:  select all the users friends as set1, then select all the other users friends as set2, then join those together where they are the same - that will give you the list you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Top query gets you the mutual friend info, and the subquery should get you the friends that @myid and @theirid shares

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   users.user_id IN (SELECT    me.friends_friend
                          FROM      friends AS me
                                    JOIN friends AS them ON me.friends_friend = them.friends_friend
                          WHERE     me.friend_user = @myid
                                    AND them.friend_user = @theirid
                                    AND me.friends_enabled = 'enabled'
                                    AND them.friends_enabled = 'enabled')
```